# How correctly use arithmetic and if-statements within a batch-file?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file

I've just started working on my first batch-file on windows, and i cant get this part through:

```
SET /p exp= "Enter Arthimetic Expression:"
SET /p ans1= "Enter Expression's Product:"
REM calculating the arthimetic expression:
SET /a ans2= %exp%
IF %ans1% == %ans2% (
ECHO Your answer is right!
) ELSE(
ECHO Your answer is wrong!
ECHO %exp% = %ans2%
)
```

this script just wont work* and I really don't know where's the problem..
(but i estimate it involves the IF and ELSE)

*it just crashes

Comment: You got a descriptive error message from cmd.exe, that `ELSE(` doesn't work. And the help of `IF /?` shows the correct syntax

Comment: Btw. The next not so obviously propblem occurs in `ECHO %exp% = %ans2%` when exp contains brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors, actually. Well - three, perhaps.

Certainly the missing space between the `ELSE` and the `(`

Then there's the strange spelling of `arithmetic` - this is critical. DOS can't handle poor spelling.

Well, in reality I tried the batch simply with the space-after-else fixed. And it crashed. It really did! For once, `it crashed` was accurate. Well - CMD didn't *actually* crash, it just returned to the prompt. No error message - nothing. Just popped up with the prompt again.

So I "FIXED" the `set /p` by removing the space after the `=`. That appeared to fix the problem, since the prompt merrily appeared the next time and all then ran smoothly.

So I decided to fix `jeb`'s point. Certainly - enter an expression like `(3*3)+42` and then an incorrect result, and you get an ugly objection.

The reason for this last behaviour is that statements are PARSED (decoded and validated) any %var% is replaced by its value at the time it was PARSED. **THEN** the statement is executed.

In consequence, If I entered `(3*3)+42` and `56`, the original expression would be parsed as

`IF 56 == 51 (ECHO Your...right!) ELSE (ECHO Your...wrong!&ECHO (3*3)+42 = 51)`

[in batch, you can cascade commands by separating them with `&`]

Now this fails validation because it appears to the parser that the `ELSE` expression  ends with the closed-parenthesis after `3*3`

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET /p exp="Enter Arithmetic Expression:"
SET /p ans1="Enter Expression's Product:"
REM calculating the arithmetic expression:
SET /a ans2= %exp%
::
:: Way the first
::
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%exp%") DO (
IF %ans1% == %ans2% (
ECHO Your answer is right!
) ELSE (
ECHO Your answer is wrong!
ECHO %%i = %ans2%
)
)
::
:: Way the second
::
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%i IN ('set exp') DO (
IF %ans1% == %ans2% (
ECHO Your answer is right!
) ELSE (
ECHO Your answer is wrong!
ECHO %%j = %ans2%
)
)
::
:: Way the third
::
SET refexp=%exp:)=^^)%
IF %ans1% == %ans2% (
ECHO Your answer is right!
) ELSE (
ECHO Your answer is wrong!
ECHO %refexp% = %ans2%
)

ECHO Note: 'SET exp' returns
SET exp
```

The first and second solutions use the analysis capacity of the `FOR /F` command (see `FOR /?` from the prompt.) The key here is that if the expression can be coaxed into the `metavariable` (the loop-control variable) then it can't be evaluated until run-time, and the parser has already validated the expression by then.

The third solution is to `"escape"` any close-parentheses by prefixing them with a caret (`^`) - see `SET /?` for documentation. When a character is escaped, its special meaning within the batch language is disregarded and it becomes just like any other character. In this case, since the caret is itself a special character with a special meaning, it itself needs to be escaped by a caret...

But the odd thing is that when I re-ran the program with the space after the `=` re-inserted, it ran happily. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

the only error, that I can find, is a missing Space between ELSE and (